# Where do I find the link to my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

I am trying to copy the link to my Stack Overflow profile but I can't find it.
How can I copy my profile link?

Comment: It's not really "an issue"... Here is the short URL to your SO Profile: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/20100262/`

Answer (score 9):

Clicking on your username or image will lead you to your profile.
Then just copy the content of the address bar.

Alternatively, you could also right-click your username and chose 'Copy Link'.

The following URL redirects to the currently logged-in user's profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/